# An alternative to <a> tag for a Hyper text-email link. JS screws up my drop down as it is based on <a> tags

Tags: javascript, css, html4

I'm stumped. Developing a website for a friend, the navigation is a drop down system that I got from http://www.dynamicdrive.com/.

The code for the drop down wants me to put links in `<a>` tags and the JS formats them into drop down elements.

What I want to do is have the second drop down, on the "Contact" element of navigation, to have contact details and an email link. I have succeeded in getting it to work in the fashion I want, except I cannot get the email adress to work as a link. If I wrap it in an `<a>` tag then the JS splits it into another element.

www.theartificialasylum.com/adex(mix_up).html

If you look at the drop down on the right, when you hover over "Contact", you will hopefully see what I mean.

If you need source code please let me know, any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is my first real adventure into web development, I can understand the javascript but it would take forever to get my head round.

html:

```
<!--1st drop down menu -->                                                   
<div id="dropmenu1_a" class="dropmenudiv_a" style="z-index:9000;"">
<a   href="artwork/nightclub_portraiture.html"><pre>NightClub Portraiture</pre></a>
<a href="artwork/wedding_photos.html"><pre>Weddings</pre></a>
<a href="artwork/urban_expo.html"><pre>Urban Expo</pre></a>
</div>

<!--2nd drop down menu -->                                                
<div id="dropmenu2_a" class="bar" style="width: 400px;" >
<a>
<pre><p class="thick">The Artificial Asylum Photography.</p></pre>
<pre>[AKA] Alistair Watt-Crawford.</pre>
<br><br>

<pre><p class="thick">Wedding and Event photography:</p></pre>
<pre>Bookings via: ali@LightsOutCollective.com</pre>
</a>

</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
//SYNTAX: tabdropdown.init("menu_id", [integer OR "auto"])
tabdropdown.init("colortab", 1)
</script>
```

css:

```
.dropmenudiv_a{
position:absolute;
top: 0;
border: 1px solid black; 
border-top-width: 8px; 
border-bottom-width: 0;
font:normal 12px Arial;
line-height:18px;
z-index:1000;
background-color: white;
width: 200px;
visibility: hidden;
}

.bar {
position:absolute;
top: 0; 
border: 1px solid black; /*THEME CHANGE HERE*/
border-top-width: 8px; 
border-bottom-width: 0;
font:normal 12px Arial;
line-height:18px;
z-index:1000;
background-color: white;
width: 200px;
visibility: hidden;
}

.bar a{
width: auto;
display: block;
text-indent: 5px;
border-top: 0 solid #678b3f;
border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; /*THEME CHANGE HERE*/
padding: 2px 0;
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
z-index:9000;
height:200px;
}

.dropmenudiv_a a{
width: auto;
display: block;
text-indent: 5px;
border-top: 0 solid #678b3f;
border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; /*THEME CHANGE HERE*/
padding: 2px 0;
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
z-index:9000;
}
```

Javascript:

```
//Drop Down Tabs Menu- Author: Dynamic Drive (http://www.dynamicdrive.com)
//Created: May 16th, 07'

var tabdropdown={
disappeardelay: 200, //set delay in miliseconds before menu disappears onmouseout
disablemenuclick: false, //when user clicks on a menu item with a drop down menu, disable menu item's link?
enableiframeshim: 1, //1 or 0, for true or false

//No need to edit beyond here////////////////////////
dropmenuobj: null, ie: document.all, firefox: document.getElementById&&!document.all, previousmenuitem:null,
currentpageurl: window.location.href.replace("http://"+window.location.hostname, "").replace(/^\//, ""), //get current page url (minus hostname, ie: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/)

getposOffset:function(what, offsettype){
    var totaloffset=(offsettype=="left")? what.offsetLeft : what.offsetTop;
    var parentEl=what.offsetParent;
        while (parentEl!=null){
            totaloffset=(offsettype=="left")? totaloffset+parentEl.offsetLeft : totaloffset+parentEl.offsetTop;
            parentEl=parentEl.offsetParent;
        }
    return totaloffset;
},

showhide:function(obj, e, obj2){ //obj refers to drop down menu, obj2 refers to tab menu item mouse is currently over
    if (this.ie || this.firefox)
        this.dropmenuobj.style.left=this.dropmenuobj.style.top="-500px"
    if (e.type=="click" && obj.visibility==hidden || e.type=="mouseover"){
        if (obj2.parentNode.className.indexOf("default")==-1) //if tab isn't a default selected one
            obj2.parentNode.className="selected"
        obj.visibility="visible"
        }
    else if (e.type=="click")
        obj.visibility="hidden"
},

iecompattest:function(){
    return (document.compatMode && document.compatMode!="BackCompat")? document.documentElement : document.body
},

clearbrowseredge:function(obj, whichedge){
    var edgeoffset=0
    if (whichedge=="rightedge"){
        var windowedge=this.ie && !window.opera? this.standardbody.scrollLeft+this.standardbody.clientWidth-15 : window.pageXOffset+window.innerWidth-15
        this.dropmenuobj.contentmeasure=this.dropmenuobj.offsetWidth
    if (windowedge-this.dropmenuobj.x < this.dropmenuobj.contentmeasure)  //move menu to the left?
        edgeoffset=this.dropmenuobj.contentmeasure-obj.offsetWidth
    }
    else{
        var topedge=this.ie && !window.opera? this.standardbody.scrollTop : window.pageYOffset
        var windowedge=this.ie && !window.opera? this.standardbody.scrollTop+this.standardbody.clientHeight-15 : window.pageYOffset+window.innerHeight-18
        this.dropmenuobj.contentmeasure=this.dropmenuobj.offsetHeight
        if (windowedge-this.dropmenuobj.y < this.dropmenuobj.contentmeasure){ //move up?
            edgeoffset=this.dropmenuobj.contentmeasure+obj.offsetHeight
            if ((this.dropmenuobj.y-topedge)<this.dropmenuobj.contentmeasure) //up no good either?
                edgeoffset=this.dropmenuobj.y+obj.offsetHeight-topedge
        }
        this.dropmenuobj.firstlink.style.borderTopWidth=(edgeoffset==0)? 0 : "1px" //Add 1px top border to menu if dropping up
    }
    return edgeoffset
},

dropit:function(obj, e, dropmenuID){
    if (this.dropmenuobj!=null){ //hide previous menu
        this.dropmenuobj.style.visibility="hidden" //hide menu
        if (this.previousmenuitem!=null && this.previousmenuitem!=obj){
            if (this.previousmenuitem.parentNode.className.indexOf("default")==-1) //If the tab isn't a default selected one
                this.previousmenuitem.parentNode.className=""
        }
    }
    this.clearhidemenu()
    if (this.ie||this.firefox){
        obj.onmouseout=function(){tabdropdown.delayhidemenu(obj)}
        obj.onclick=function(){return !tabdropdown.disablemenuclick} //disable main menu item link onclick?
        this.dropmenuobj=document.getElementById(dropmenuID)
        this.dropmenuobj.onmouseover=function(){tabdropdown.clearhidemenu()}
        this.dropmenuobj.onmouseout=function(e){tabdropdown.dynamichide(e, obj)}
        this.dropmenuobj.onclick=function(){tabdropdown.delayhidemenu(obj)}
        this.showhide(this.dropmenuobj.style, e, obj)
        this.dropmenuobj.x=this.getposOffset(obj, "left")
        this.dropmenuobj.y=this.getposOffset(obj, "top")
        this.dropmenuobj.style.left=this.dropmenuobj.x-this.clearbrowseredge(obj, "rightedge")+"px"
        this.dropmenuobj.style.top=this.dropmenuobj.y-this.clearbrowseredge(obj, "bottomedge")+obj.offsetHeight+1+"px"
        this.previousmenuitem=obj //remember main menu item mouse moved out from (and into current menu item)
        this.positionshim() //call iframe shim function
    }
},

contains_firefox:function(a, b) {
    while (b.parentNode)
    if ((b = b.parentNode) == a)
        return true;
    return false;
},

dynamichide:function(e, obj2){ //obj2 refers to tab menu item mouse is currently over
    var evtobj=window.event? window.event : e
    if (this.ie&&!this.dropmenuobj.contains(evtobj.toElement))
        this.delayhidemenu(obj2)
    else if (this.firefox&&e.currentTarget!= evtobj.relatedTarget&& !this.contains_firefox(evtobj.currentTarget, evtobj.relatedTarget))
        this.delayhidemenu(obj2)
},

delayhidemenu:function(obj2){
    this.delayhide=setTimeout(function(){tabdropdown.dropmenuobj.style.visibility='hidden'; if (obj2.parentNode.className.indexOf('default')==-1) obj2.parentNode.className=''},this.disappeardelay) //hide menu
},

clearhidemenu:function(){
    if (this.delayhide!="undefined")
        clearTimeout(this.delayhide)
},

positionshim:function(){ //display iframe shim function
    if (this.enableiframeshim && typeof this.shimobject!="undefined"){
        if (this.dropmenuobj.style.visibility=="visible"){
            this.shimobject.style.width=this.dropmenuobj.offsetWidth+"px"
            this.shimobject.style.height=this.dropmenuobj.offsetHeight+"px"
            this.shimobject.style.left=this.dropmenuobj.style.left
            this.shimobject.style.top=this.dropmenuobj.style.top
        }
    this.shimobject.style.display=(this.dropmenuobj.style.visibility=="visible")? "block" : "none"
    }
},

hideshim:function(){
    if (this.enableiframeshim && typeof this.shimobject!="undefined")
        this.shimobject.style.display='none'
},

isSelected:function(menuurl){
var menuurl=menuurl.replace("http://"+menuurl.hostname, "").replace(/^\//, "")
return (tabdropdown.currentpageurl==menuurl)
},

init:function(menuid, dselected){
    this.standardbody=(document.compatMode=="CSS1Compat")? document.documentElement : document.body //create reference to common "body" across doctypes
    var menuitems=document.getElementById(menuid).getElementsByTagName("a")
    for (var i=0; i<menuitems.length; i++){
        if (menuitems[i].getAttribute("rel")){
            var relvalue=menuitems[i].getAttribute("rel")
            document.getElementById(relvalue).firstlink=document.getElementById(relvalue).getElementsByTagName("a")[0]
            menuitems[i].onmouseover=function(e){
                var event=typeof e!="undefined"? e : window.event
                tabdropdown.dropit(this, event, this.getAttribute("rel"))
            }
        }
        if (dselected=="auto" && typeof setalready=="undefined" && this.isSelected(menuitems[i].href)){
            menuitems[i].parentNode.className+=" selected default"
            var setalready=true
        }
        else if (parseInt(dselected)==i)
            menuitems[i].parentNode.className+=" selected default"
    }
}

}
```

Comment: An example of code would be much clearer.

Comment: Please always post the relevant markup and code *in the question*, don't just link to it. Why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Comment: Yeah Sorry, I'm confusing people here. For this second drop down, I just want some info and want it to contain the contact email adress as a click-able email adress. This drop down is not a menu, unlike the first, there should be no active link, although it is contained within the <a> tag. I am using the <a> tag, because the drop-down system I am using uses it to seperate elements within the drop down. I want to modify it to allow the contact drop-down to act like a modular window. I hope that helps!

Comment: Right people, If you are still interested in helping.. 
(I apologise for not getting back in touch sooner, I was out for a couple of days for a friend's 21st birthday party!).

Comment: If I do not enclose the code/info for the "contact" drop down in a <a> tag, it will not work as a drop down menu. Everything in the contact drop down is enclosed within an <a> tag. If I take the <a> tag out then the "contact" will not drop down. I dont want the actual "contact" tab to be a link and I dont want the whole of the "contact" drop-down area to be a link. I want the drop down from "contact" to be some text, with a clickable email link. But the JS that runs the drop down, wants each drop down element to be surrounded in <a> tags.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the menu code, it looks to me like if the `<a>` tag doesn't have a `rel` attribute, the link isn't turned into a drop-down.  You should be able to just put the contact link in without a `rel` tag.

If this suggestion isn't working for you, then please show us exactly what HTML you're trying to use that doesn't work for you (ideally in a working/non-working example).

Comment: Hey, I gave all the javascript and as much as I can think is relevant of the html. Notice how everything in the 2nd drop down is enclosed in an <a> tag. If I enclose the email adress in a nested <a> tag, within the greater <a> tag, the javascript splits it into a new drop down element, like in the first drop down.

Comment: Is there another tag, an alternative to the <a> tag, that would allow me to display the email adress as a link. <b href="email@.."> ?

Comment: Your comments have us thoroughly confused.  If you don't want it to be clickable link in the drop down menu, then don't use a link.  The popup menu doesn't have to have any links in it as best I can tell so just use your own HTML to format it the way you want.  You don't have to rely on formatting from the code.  Just use your own HTML (without `<a>` links in it).  Right now, the contact link isn't hooked up to a drop-down menu at all (it doesn't have a `rel` attribute).

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood right your question, you can't create more than one tab. Or was it removed, because you couldn't get it work?

The code below is copied from your page, with some changes.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//SYNTAX: tabdropdown.init("menu_id", [integer OR "auto"]);
tabdropdown.init("colortab", "auto");
tabdropdown.init("your_second_tab", "auto");
</script>
```

Add then the `DIV` like `dropmenu1_a`, which contains links in "Contact".